# Building with EAS BUILDING fails

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, watermelondb

I'm working in a Expo ejected project (Expo SDK 44, WatermelonDB 0.24.0). When I try to build de project (eas build), I get those erros:

````
[RUN_FASTLANE] › Compiling react-native-svg Pods/RNSVG » RNSVGMarker.m
[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸ The following build commands failed:
[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸        CompileSwift normal arm64 (in target 'WatermelonDB' from project 'Pods')
[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸        CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'WatermelonDB' from project 'Pods')
[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸        CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'expo-dev-menu' from project 'Pods')
```

Any help? Any clue?

Thanks,
Martín
````